# Can SQL Server Management Studio be configured to only query data and not alter database tables on the server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Trying to understand if SSMS can be configured to only query data from server tables and not alter the tables themselves.  In short, can the flow of info be restricted to only one way...from the server to SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: The permissions of the user you use to login is what determine what ultimately you're able to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to put the users that you want only to query data in a group that has only rights to query data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Zdravko!

Answer (score 2):

Permissions should be configured so that only the properly authorized users can alter the table schema.  If your organization is currently using one database login for everything, that needs to stop.   Typically, you'll have a level of read-only users, a level of read-write users, a level of read-write-execute (for stored procedures) users, and Administrative users.   Trying to make the UI application restrict functions by itself won't work, as more than just Sql Server Management Studio can connect to SQL Server.   Basic users should be set up as read-only.  Applications should have whatever permissions group they need, though never Admin and each application should have its own specialized login.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!